# C++ ctime to see seconds elapse not functioning properly. Fibonacci

Tags: c++, fibonacci, seconds

```
int main() {

clock_t start, finish;
double elapsedTime;
start = clock();

unsigned __int64 result = fibonacci_recursion(300);



finish = clock();
elapsedTime = (finish - start);
cout << "result is " << result << endl;
cout << "Time required = " << elapsedTime << " seconds " << endl;


}


unsigned __int64 fibonacci_recursion(int number) {

unsigned __int64 result = 1;

if (number > 2) {
    int firstNumber = 1;
    int secondNumber = 1;
    int swapHolder;
    for (int i = 3; i <= number; ++i) {
        swapHolder = firstNumber + secondNumber;
        firstNumber = secondNumber;
        secondNumber = swapHolder;
    }
    result = swapHolder;
}

return result;
}
```

The function is the recursive method to do the fibonacci number sequence. Recursion for this should take a while. According to our instructor, the time should be longer. Like...a over a few seconds. I keep getting 0.Is my computer just really fast?

Comment: The function isn't recursive.

Comment: _"The function is the recursive method to do the fibonacci number sequence."_ In what way?

Comment: If you actually had a recursive implementation, and `fib(300)` were representable with 64 bits, your program would take many times the lifetime of the universe to complete.

Answer (score 3):

A 64 bit number can contain about 20 digits. Fib 300 seems to be around 60 digits or 222232244629420445529739893461909967206666939096499764990979600. So you can't expect a good result.

Also, you aren't doing any recursion, which is why you get the quick result.

A recursive solution would be a function that contains calls to itself like

```
really_really_big_int_t rec_fib(int n){
    if (n < 1) return 0; // catch invalid values
    if (n < 3) return 1; // catch recursion base case
    return rec_fib(n - 1) + rec_fib(n - 2);
}
```

Fibonacci numbers are used here to illustrate recursion because it is a very simple case. A recursive approach to actually calculate the Fibonacci numbers would be a very poor solution. It leads to many, many unnecessary calculations. This is however why you are asked to time it in your lab. It would show that some algorithms take an unreasonable amount of time even for small inputs (300).

The iterative approach that you have provided in your question is very much preferred.

Comment: That's it, I'm proposing `std::really_really_big_int_t` right now :D